# Any $n$-tuple of elements of $G$ belongs to at most $n$ collections $G_j$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Im reading a proof and I get lost in a phrase. The statement to be proved:

> Let $X$ a topological space and $G_0$ a collection of subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property. Then there exists a maximal collection $G$ of subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property that contains $G_0$.

Now the proof starts like this:

> The family of all collections of sets with the finite intersection property and
>   containing $G_0$ is partially ordered by inclusion, so that by the Hausdorff principle there is a maximal linearly ordered subfamily $F$. We claim that $G$ is the union of all the collections in $F$.
>
> **Any $n$-tuple $\{E_1 ,...,E_n \}$ of elements of $G$ belongs to at most $n$ collections $G_j$**. Since $\{G_j\}$ is linearly ordered there is a collection $G_n$ that contains the others.

...and so on.

But I can't follow the emphasized phrase, indeed I have a lot of counterexamples: by example let the collection $G_0:=\{(0,1),\,(0,2),\, (0,3)\}$ of subsets of $\Bbb R $. Then $G_0$ have the finite intersection property and a chain of collections that contains $G_0$ can be defined recursively by $G_n:=G_{n-1}\cup (0,3+n)$. Now let $G:=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 0}G_n$, and so the $3$-tuple defined by $G_0$ belongs to every $G_n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N $, not just to at most three collections of the chain.

Maybe Im misunderstanding the emphasized phrase, due to a lack of knowledge of the english language? Or maybe it is just a typographic error and it must say "at least" instead of "at most", what seems to have more sense in a linearly ordered chain. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: you can read the original text of the proof [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=xPsXDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=The+family+of+all+collections+of+sets+with+the+finite+intersection+property+and+containing+G0+is+partially+ordered+by+inclusion,+so+that+by+the+Hausdorff+principle+there+is+a+maximal+linearly+ordered+subfamily+F.+We+claim+that+G+is+the+union+of+all+the+collections+in+F.&source=bl&ots=G36KAEjzmR&sig=ACfU3U1qGLVijtCgqKCKWv8vMpkjmPHMfw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKk_q6nOLnAhVFzIUKHezQDzEQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20family%20of%20all%20collections%20of%20sets%20with%20the%20finite%20intersection%20property%20and%20containing%20G0%20is%20partially%20ordered%20by%20inclusion%2C%20so%20that%20by%20the%20Hausdorff%20principle%20there%20is%20a%20maximal%20linearly%20ordered%20subfamily%20F.%20We%20claim%20that%20G%20is%20the%20union%20of%20all%20the%20collections%20in%20F.&f=false).

Comment: The sentence is weird. I think what the author wanted to say is that for any $E_1,\ldots, E_n$ of elements of $G$ there is $G_n\in F$ such that $E_i\in G_n$ for all $i$. This follows by taking $G_{i,n}\in F$ such that $E_i\in G_{i,n}$ and since $\{G_{i,n}\}_{i}$ are linearly ordered by inclusion then the maximal element is our $G_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with @freakish' comment. The author means that if we have a maximal chain $\mathcal{F}$ in the poset with union $\mathcal{G}$, and any set $\{E_1,E_2,\ldots, E_n\}$ (it's not a tuple) that is a subset of $\mathcal{G}$, we can find (at most) $n$ families $\mathcal{G_j}\in \mathcal{F}, j \le n$ such that $E_i \in \mathcal{G}_i$ for all $i$, just by the definition of a union, and as the set of families $\mathcal{F}$ is linearly ordered by inclusion, one of them $\mathcal{G}_{j_0}$ say, is the largest and so all $E_i$ lies in that one family (that has the FIP by virtue of being in the poset at all) and so $\bigcap_{i=1}^n E_i$ is non-empty, etc.

It's a special case of the argument that for a property of finite character we can always has a maximal family with that property, a special case of Zorn (also used in the proof of a basis in a vector space, and in a proof of the Alexander subbase lemma etc.). This is known as the [Teichmüller-Tukey lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller%E2%80%93Tukey_lemma).

Comment: the expression "at most" is seriously misleading here, because indeed if $\{E_1,\ldots ,E_n\}\subset G_j$ for some $j$ then, due to be the collection linearly ordered and infinite, there are infinitely many $G_k$ such that $\{E_1,\ldots ,E_n\}\subset G_k$. Also in the book I see other wrong argumentations (I will avoid this book for sure).

Comment: @Masacroso He means you only need $n$ many in this argument, not that there are $n$ many in total. The argument itself is fine, just clumsily written.